# Confusion Matrix and probability threshold using confusioMatrix in R

Tags: r, confusion-matrix

I am getting this error message when I try using confusionMatrix
Error: `data` and `reference` should be factors with the same levels.
This is my code for a glm model with an ROC curve

```
library(pROC)
library(caret)
library(e1071)
library(regclass)
#set.seed(6)
train_sample<-sample(400,250)
BF<-as.data.frame(Analysis_16_1_21a)
BF$fm<-as.factor(BF$fm)
BF_train<-BF[train_sample,]
BF_test<-BF[-train_sample,]
m <- train(fm ~ ., data=BF_train, method = "glmboost")
p<-predict(m,BF_test,type="prob")
roc(BF_test$fm, p[,-1],plot=TRUE,legacy.axes=TRUE)
confusionMatrix(BF_test$fm,p[,-1],threshold=0.5)
```

The R documentation says that actual is a vector of labels and predicted is a vector of predicted values. If these are both binary factors how can the threshold be adjusted? I want to adjust the threshold for the probabilities to see the impact on the confusion matrix. Can anyone help? I am new to this and expect it is a beginners error! Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)! Please could you add a sample of the `Analysis_16_1_21a` dataset?

Comment: Thanks- this is healthcare data so difficult to share, but the dataset consists of 400 rows of 10 variables all of which are numeric. The dependent variable is a binary factor.

Answer (score 0):

Guess that there should be some sort of problem with the `threshold` part of the confusion matrix.

By applying an ifelse statement cleaning it worked. Also I double checked with the `table` statement.

Here's the full code, which you can try. Without a data sample I've created my own df based on you requirements.

```
#Dataframe creation
Analysis_16_1_21a <- sample(1:50, 10, replace=FALSE)
for (i in 1:8){
  Analysis_16_1_21a <- data.frame(Analysis_16_1_21a, sample(1:50, 10, replace=FALSE))
}
#str(Analysis_16_1_21a)
Analysis_16_1_21a <- data.frame(Analysis_16_1_21a, c(1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0))
colnames(Analysis_16_1_21a) <- c("X1","X2","X3","X4","X5","X6","X7","X8","X9","fm")

library(pROC)
library(caret)
library(e1071)
library(regclass)
#set.seed(6)
train_sample <- sample(1:nrow(Analysis_16_1_21a), size=0.7 * nrow(Analysis_16_1_21a))
BF<-as.data.frame(Analysis_16_1_21a)
BF$fm<-as.factor(BF$fm)
BF_train<-BF[train_sample,]
BF_test<-BF[-train_sample,]
m <- train(fm ~ ., data=BF_train, method = "glmboost")
p<-predict(m,BF_test,type="prob")
roc(BF_test$fm, p[,-1],plot=TRUE,legacy.axes=TRUE)
#new confusion matrix
predicted<-as.factor(ifelse(p[,-1]> 0.5,1,0))
confusionMatrix(BF_test$fm,predicted)
#alternative way to get a confusion matrix
table(BF_test$fm,as.factor(p[,-1]> 0.5))
```